# Coffee-Reactify Compilation Issue

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs, browserify

I'm really hoping someone can help me with this issue because I've searched high and low to no avail and tried everything I can think of. I'm new to ReactJS and Browserify (though I don't think this has anything to do with Browserify) and can't seem to get this code working. I've been following along with the video series "Getting Started With React.js," and section 5.2 introduces Browserify and setting it up properly to work with React. Using plain old JavaScript, I'm able to get it working no problem, but when I try to use Coffee-Reactify and CoffeeScript, everything compiles fine, but when I load the page, I get this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined"

When I follow the stack trace, it seems to error out in the findComponentRoot method of React, which I haven't touched. This leads me to believe there's something wrong with my CoffeeScript, but I've compared it line for line with the JavaScript, and aside from the additional "return" statements the CoffeeScript compiler adds, nothing seems too different. If anyone out there can replicate or identify my issue, I'd greatly appreciate it! Here is the code for all of my files, and thank you all very much in advance!

index.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title React Tools
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')

  body
    #app
    script(src='bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js')
    script(src='bower_components/react/react.js')
    script(src='build/app.js')
```

app.coffee

```
MessageBox = require('./MessageBox.cjsx')

reactComponent = React.render(
  <MessageBox />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

SubMessage.cjsx

```
SubMessage = React.createClass

handleDelete: (e) ->
    @props.onDelete(@props.message)

propTypes:
  message: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired

getDefaultProps: ->
  message: "It's good to see you"

render: ->
  <div>
    {@props.message}
    <button onClick={@handleDelete} className='btn btn-danger'>x</button>
  </div>

module.exports = SubMessage
```

MessageBox.cjsx

```
React = require 'react'
SubMessage = require './SubMessage.cjsx'

MessageBox = React.createClass

  deleteMessage: (message) ->
    newMessages = _.without(@state.messages, message)
    @setState
      messages: newMessages

  handleAdd: (e) ->
    newMessage = @refs.newMessage.getDOMNode().value
    newMessages = @state.messages.concat [newMessage]
    @setState
      messages: newMessages

  getInitialState: ->
    isVisible: true,
    messages: [
      'I like the world',
      'Coffee flavored ice cream is underrated',
      'My spoon is too big',
      'Tuesday is coming.',
      'I am a banana'
    ]

  render: ->

    inlineStyles =
      display: if @state.isVisible then 'block' else 'none'

    messages = @state.messages.map ((message) ->
      <SubMessage message={message} onDelete={@deleteMessage} />
    ).bind(@)

    return (
      <div className='container jumbotron' style={inlineStyles}>
        <h2>Hello, World</h2>
        <input ref='newMessage' type='text' />
        <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={@handleAdd}>Add</button>
        { messages }
      </div>
    )

module.exports = MessageBox
```

As a side note, React is partially "working" because the messages array gets mapped to a SubMessage array and displays properly with the delete buttons. So the error seems to be happening at a later point in the cycle. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what an oversight on my part. It turns out I was loading React from two different places, once as a node module in my coffee/cjsx files and again in my HTML, but from a bower-installed version of React. I can't believe I spent so much time on this, but hopefully my struggle helps somebody else!

Comment: I'll mark this as resolved tomorrow, when I can, but I still find it somewhat curious that when not using CoffeeScript and just using JavaScript, the same issue didn't present, even though React was still being loaded twice. I don't know enough about coffee-reactify, but I suspect it could be the culprit. If anyone has some insight into this, please keep this thread alive, as I can see it being helpful to others in the future.